# Spring Boot Thymeleaf - iterator variable odd & even checks gives reversed results

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to thymeleaf and following couple of tutorials to iterate over list and display checkboxes in odd/even fashion. Surprisingly, i'm getting wierd results. Below is code snippet:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
                        <th:block th:each="service,iterStat : ${services}">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="myCheck"/> 
                            <label  class="form-check-label" th:text="${'myCheck'+iterStat.index+'_'+iterStat.odd}"></label>
                        </div>
                        </th:block>
                    </div>
```

indexes 0,2,4 etc prints odd as true and 1,3,5 prints odd as false.

[image]

I'm not sure whether im doing correct or not. FYI im using spring-boot version 2.5.2 and thymeleaf version 3.0.12.

Comment: `odd` or `even` is based on `count` not `index`. Where `index` is 0 based, count is 1 based.

Comment: Oh .. Thank you very much for the clarification.. but its little confusing when html elements dynamically assigned `index` to their ids ..  :(

Comment: Ignore..got it.. using `count` to ids instead of `index` solve the problem.. once again, thank you very much.. i was banging my head since 1hr to understand this.. :)